# Accessing FTP on different port using Finder

Tags: macos

Just wondering, is it possible accessing FTP on different port (not port 21) using Finder? For example if I have FTP port opened at port 8021 - 
how can I access that FTP server at that port using Finder?

If I'm accessing it using Terminal, it's working like a charm and I have no issue with that.

I want to use Finder because it will be integrated in the side bar, and that makes my life easier when transferring the files to the server.

Comment: Does adding `:8021` to the end of the address not work?

Comment: somehow it doesnt work. adding :8021 or put space and then 8021 it's not working either.

Comment: This is strange behavior. Are you using Finder's "Connect to Server" menu option? Also, the format for ports is [address]:[port], no spaces.

Comment: yes, I was using "Connect to Server" options, I was trying [address(space)port] also not working...